# In how many ways can I split 151 different objects into 3 categories?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

> In how many ways can I split 151 different objects into 3 categories
>   such that no category gets absolute majority?

I figured that the answer should be:

${{151+3-1}\choose{3-1}}-3{{76+3-1}\choose{3-1}}=2619$ but I don't understand these formulas.

**What I am thinking:**

There are ${{151}\choose{a}}$ ways to choose $a$ number of objects from $151$.

There are ${{151}\choose{b}}$ ways to choose $b$ objects and ${{151}\choose{c}}$ for $c$. Also $c=151-a-b$.

Thus I think I need to sum the binomial from $1\leq a\leq 75$ and $1\leq b\leq 150-a$ s.t. $b\leq 75$ and finally $1\leq c \leq 151-a-b$

Can anyone advice me how to figure it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are looking for all the tuples $(i,j,k)$ such that $i,j,k< \frac{151}{2}$ and $i+j+k=151$. Start with the solution $(75,75,1)$. We can decrease $j$ and increase $k$ by 1 to get $(75,74,2)$. Continuing in this fashion, we arrive at $(75,1,75)$, which gives rise to $75$ solutions when $i=75$. We then decrease $i$ by one and start with $(74,75,2)$. Apply the same process and see that there are $74$ solutions this time.

Continue until $i=1$, and you should have the answer being $\sum_{n=1}^{75} n$.

Answer (score 2):

HINTS:
There are $3^{151}$ ways to assign 151 seats to three parties.
There are ${151\choose76}2^{75}$ ways for Party A to get 76 seats.

Comment: thanks, I get $3^{151}-3\times \sum_{a=76}^{151} {151\choose a}2^{151-a}$, but how do I get rid of such high powers?

Comment: I don't know, sorry.